# Date range validations wont allow update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some custom validations on my `reservation_start` and `reservation_end` attributes on my model

```
class DateRangeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.date_ranges.each do |range|
      if range.include? value
        record.errors.add(attribute, "#{options[:name]} not available")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The Reservation model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :transport

  validates_presence_of :user, :transport, :reservation_start, :reservation_end

  validates :reservation_start, 
    date_range: {name: "Start date"},
    date_past:  true

  validates :reservation_end, 
    date_range:   {name:  "End date"},
    date_subset:  true,
    start_bigger: true

  def date_ranges
    reservations = Reservation.where(["transport_id =?", transport_id])
    reservations.map { |e| e.reservation_start..e.reservation_end }
  end

end
```

The problem with this is that if I want to for example, edit a record to decrease the `reservation_end` by one day the validations kicks in. I tried setting the validation to `on: :create` but that is not a good idea.

What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your post what you're trying to validate without you also including the model.  Why is it a problem if the validations run when you want to decrease `reservation_end`?  Does the validation then fail?  If that's the case it sounds like your validation isn't setup quite right.

Comment: It wont let me decrease `reservation_end` because its already in use by the very record im trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought is to change your query in `date_ranges` to exclude the current record, should it already be persisted (ie. the `id` field has been populated).  It would look something like:

```
def date_ranges
  reservations = Reservation.where({transport_id: transport_id})
  reservations = reservations.where(['id <> ?', id]) if !id.nil?
  reservations.map { |e| e.reservation_start..e.reservation_end }
end
```

The line `reservations = reservations.where(['id <> ?', id]) if !id.nil?` should exclude the current record iff (if and only if) it has already been persisted, in which case the validation should pass when editing a previously created `Reservation` so long as it does not overlap any other `Reservation`.

Comment: Oh god, how did I not notice that.

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)